# How do you push in pycharm if the commit was already done?

Tags: python, pycharm, push, commit

Once you commit in pycharm it takes you to a second window to go through with the push. But if you only hit commit and not commit/push then how do you bring up the push option. You can't do another commit unless changes are made.

Answer (score 2):

In the upper menu [VCS] -> [Git...] -> [Push]